# i fetched products from mysqli data and how to sort product within the results with help of input type

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<div class="row item-display">
              <?php
               if(isset($_GET['offers'])){
                    $cpro_query ="SELECT * FROM product WHERE offers!='no offers'";
                  }elseif(isset($_POST['search-title'])){
                    $search =$_POST['search-title'];
                    $cpro_query ="SELECT * FROM product WHERE tag LIKE '%$search%'";
                  }
                  else{
                  $cpro_query = "SELECT * FROM product";
              }
              if(isset($cat_name)){
                $cpro_query.=" WHERE cat_name='$cat_name'";
              }elseif(isset($brand_name)){
                $cpro_query.=" WHERE brand_name='$brand_name'";
              }else{
              $cpro_query.=" ORDER BY product_id DESC";
            }

              $cpro_run = mysqli_query($con,$cpro_query);
              if(mysqli_num_rows($cpro_run)>0){
                while ($cpro_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cpro_run)) {
                  $pro_id = $cpro_row['product_id'];
                  $pro_title = $cpro_row['title'];
                  $pro_image = $cpro_row['image1'];
                  $pro_desc = substr($cpro_row['description'],0,100);
                  $pro_cost = $cpro_row['cost'];
                  $pro_rating = $cpro_row['rating'];
              ?>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href='single-item-display.php?pro_id=<?php echo $pro_id; ?>'><div class="panel">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="item" >
                  <p><?php echo $pro_desc;?></p>
                  <p>Price:<span class="fa fa-rupee"><?php echo $pro_cost;?>/-</span></p>
                  <p><?php require('inc/rating.php');?></p>
                  <h4 style="color:#E80C4F;"><?php echo $pro_title;?></h4>
                </div></a>
              </div>
              <?php
              }
            }else{
              echo "<center><span style='color:red;'>No products yet<span></center>";
            }
              ?>

            </div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="product-categorywise.php?lh=<?php echo $lh;?>">Price Low to High </a>
                      <a href="product-categorywise.php?hl=<?php echo $hl?>">Price High to Low </a>
                      <a href="product-categorywise.php?fa=<?php echo $lh?>">Fresh Arrivals </a>
                      <a href="product-categorywise.php?di=<?php echo $lh?>">Discount </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
```

How can i sort products from price high to low or low to high within the resulted products.not from all products in database.i have listings like sort by color,brand,type,size like this.so how to write query or how to make functionality.?

Comment: u can do this with the help of datatables
https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just add in query like
$cpro_query.=" ORDER BY product_id DESC, price DESC"; // sorting by product id and price as desc order

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderfield = 'product_id';
if (isset($_GET['orderfield'])) {
    if ($_GET['orderfield']=='someotherfield') {
        $orderfield = 'someotherfield';
    }
}

$orderdir = 'DESC';
if (isset($_GET['orderdir'])) {
    if ($_GET['orderdir']=='asc') {
        $orderdir = 'ASC';
    }
}

$cpro_query.=" ORDER BY ' . $orderfield . ' ' . $orderdir;
```